# ASP.NET MVC Core app in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a mostly desktop developer, although I have had limited experience with ASP.NET MVC in the past. I have also had some experience with self managed web hosting and deploying website using IIS.

What I am interested in doing now is trying out Azure - deploying a test ASP.NET MVC Core app on there, using a tiny database. What I am struggling to understand is the pricing model of Azure - they provide pricing per hour, depending on service. I was able to find the SQL DB service, which ended up costing $5 per month, but was unable to find a basic IIS or things like domain name on there. Am I missing the point of Azure? Is domain name.. outside of Azure domain?

Any thoughts/examples/links on Azure pricing vs using one of the myriad of smaller hosts out there?

What I currently have with a couple of different providers is:

- Domain Name
- Windows Server hosting with IIS & SQL DB
- Dedicated IP
- SSL certificate

Thanks!!

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/

Comment: Are you using visual studio for the website?

Comment: Yes I am - always using Visual Studio :)

Comment: You should find hosting a new website option directly from visual studio. It can take care of the whole process without having to open the azure portal. You can select the sub domain, plan etc

Answer (score 1):

You create a web app for hosting a website. By default they provide a website with the subdomain under azurewebsites.net. For the basic package, you can connect with your domain (if you have any) with a DNS cname. Based on the pricing that starts from free, you can take more expensive packages to get Dedicated IP, SSL, Custom domain etc.

You can check the pricing here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

Note that you can use ftp, you can publish directly from visual studio. Or better, you can create the website directly from vs without opening azure portal under the publish option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try out Azure, you can start with `Free` tier of Azure App Service. If you want to have custom domain, you need to go at least with `Shared` tier or above as per your needs.
You can see more details over here - 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/

Feature like dedicated public IP and SSLs are also supported by Azure, according to the tier you choose. For example, SSL is available in `Basic` tier and above.

Please note that, an Azure app service belongs within an `App Service Plan`, you can have look at detailed features and pricing of app plans here -
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/plans/

You may choose SQL DB for your application. Pricing available here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/sql-database/

Comment: Thanks for the info! That is making a bit more sense. When they provide the costs (e.g. $0.075) - it's all per hour, regardless of usage right? So to get the monthly cost, I would just multiply that by ~730? So that's just under $55 dollars a month? That's hosting alone, then I would add the DB price on top of that?

Just making sure that I'm understanding this correctly

Comment: In the azure's pricing website there is an option to convert everything from hourly to monthly. and yes, shared hosting (cheapest paid) comes around $9/m and as you know cheapest website comes around $4.99. However Free websites are still good enough for development